# Como comentar / documentar uma tabela?

Tags: mysql

Vi em um banco de dados PostGreSQL que cada tabela e cada campo das tabelas tem um comentário explicando pra que serve cada um. Segue modelo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero saber se no MySQL é possível fazer algo semelhante. Caso não seja, existe algum programa externo pra fazer essa documentação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim é possível basta adicionar a clásula `COMMENT` na definição da coluna ou tabela.

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'chave primária',
  nome VARCHAR(50) COMMENT 'coluna com o nome',
  email VARCHAR(50) COMMENT 'contato da pessoas',
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)COMMENT 'tabela contendo informações de pessoas'
```

Para recuperar os comentários das tabelas/colunas pode usar o comando:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM pessoa
```

Para uma consulta mais refinada use o [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html):

```
SELECT table_name, table_comment FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'nome_da_database'
```

Caso utilize o workbench click no icone com a letra `i` na aba `info` são mostrados os comentários da tabela e na `columns` os comentários referentes a cada coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Baseado em:** [Show Comment of Fields FROM Mysql Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5404051/1342547)

Comment: tem como imprimir?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo já atualizo a resposta.