# Como ler os comentários dos campos da tabela MySQL?

Tags: mysql, table, comentários, campos

Esse comando

> SHOW COLUMNS FROM [nome da tabela];

Mostra os campos de uma tabela e os detalhes mais importantes deles

Eu preciso ler os comentários do campo, exemplo:

> COLUMN `cod_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'CÓDIGO DE
>   CLIENTE'

Essa parte eu peguei no codigo de create da tabela

Precisaria ler com conteudo de "**COMMENT**"

Comment: Olhe essa resposta: [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185269/92908)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

já achei o comando

> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM [TABLE];

A fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404051/show-comment-of-fields-from-mysql-table

Answer (score 2):

Existe um banco de dados chamado `information_schema`, esse banco de dados é responsável por armazenar as estruturas de todos os bancos de dados.

Para você pegar o comentário de uma coluna pode selecionar a tabela `COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT a.`COLUMN_COMMENT`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` a
WHERE a.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'seu_banco' AND a.`TABLE_NAME` = 'sua_tabela' AND a.`COLUMN_NAME` = 'sua_coluna';
```

Aliás, essa tabela armazena todas as informações de uma coluna, não só o comentário. Esse banco de dados também é útil para outras coisas, como por exemplo pegar todas as informações das tabelas de um banco específico:

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` a
WHERE a.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'seu_banco'
```

Comment: A fonte seria essa: [FONTE](https://forum.zwame.pt/threads/obter-comment-do-field-de-1-tabela-mysql.189876/)? Caso sim, põe na resposta. ✌️

Comment: Então Roberto no mesmo momento que vc estava colocando sua resposta acabei achando um comando bem simples: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM TABELA;
O FULL traz todos os pormenores da tabela, agradeço pela resposta

Comment: @rbz, a fonte não foi essa, inclusive montei o `SELECT` manualmente no meu `menangement`.

Comment: @Marcelo, o importante é ter o problema resolvido.